# Replace stop light switch cushion - 2003 Toyota Camry Altise

Tags: toyota, brakes, camry

So my brake lights are always on and it is the stop light cushion. I have purchased a new one from the dealer and now need to replace.

I have tried pointy nose pliers and they are just not working. I suspect I may have to remove just the switch itself to gain easier access to snap the cushion into place.

So is there any tricks in doing this without having to remove either the switch or the entire brake pedal assembly?

Answer (score 3):

I found the easiest way to undo the 3 bolts holding the fuse and wiring distribution board and undoing a couple of the looms.

With this done, you can then move this out of the way and gain side access to the brake pedal. With some slight patience you can insert the stop light cushion into place.

Comment: @Mark Johnson - No photos/Diagram. But easy to do if you think it will make this question & answer better for the site.

Comment: @Wayne Yes please, that would help immensely.

Comment: @Tim/@Mark - Ok, I will try to organise some photos of the old car interior quality not high, but still can show others the little steps required for the non-mechanic to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

racq mechanic glued a 10 cent piece in place of the original plastic bumper in front of the stop light switch works great. but how the hell he contorted himself to do this is beyond me. I have now purchased a replacement bumper from Toyota and will await the time when this 10 cent piece falls off and I will try to insert the proper bumper into position.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to replace that coin. Its made of metal and will NEVER crack like that piece of garbage that Toyota put in at the factory. Your NEW PLASTIC part is doomed to fail just as that factory one did

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/64648)